# Hide (minimize) JQgrid details on page load

Tags: jqgrid

probably a simple question, but how can i get a JQgrid to load minimized. When you hit the little arrow at the top right of the grid, it only shows the grid title. I would like a grid on my page to be like this as the page loads, and when the user hits the button it shows the grid data again

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're configuring the grid, try setting the `hiddengrid` to `true`. See [this page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) for the various options.